# BeautifulSoup error while accesing a td inside a tr

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

this is the HTML that I'm trying to access, But am unable to access the 2nd `td` inside the `tr`.

Below is the `HTML` source code:

```html
<tbody>
 <!-- ngRepeat: record in records | orderBy: query.fullname -->
 <tr class="hand_cursor ng-scope" ng-click="create_dialog(record)" ng-repeat="record in records | orderBy: query.fullname" style="" title="View Details">
  <td class="ng-binding">22184</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">Abercrombie, Dave J.</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">Feb 14, 2020</td>
  <td align="right" class="ng-binding">F0517CC - Fld 05 West Section C</td>
 </tr>
 <!-- end ngRepeat: record in records | orderBy: query.fullname -->
 <tr class="hand_cursor ng-scope" ng-click="create_dialog(record)" ng-repeat="record in records | orderBy: query.fullname" title="View Details">
  <td class="ng-binding">14075</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">Abeyta, Patricia F.</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">Feb 28, 2018</td>
  <td align="right" class="ng-binding">F1228 - JMC Packing House Plantation Management</td>
 </tr>
 <!-- end ngRepeat: record in records | orderBy: query.fullname -->
 <tr class="hand_cursor ng-scope" ng-click="create_dialog(record)" ng-repeat="record in records | orderBy: query.fullname" title="View Details">
  <td class="ng-binding">43296</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">Acevedo, Patricia W.</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">Jun 23, 2017</td>
  <td align="right" class="ng-binding">F0517CC - Fld 05 West Section C</td>
 </tr>
 <!-- end ngRepeat: record in records | orderBy: query.fullname -->
 <tr class="hand_cursor ng-scope" ng-click="create_dialog(record)" ng-repeat="record in records | orderBy: query.fullname" title="View Details">
  <td class="ng-binding">45023</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">Ackerman, Brittany B.</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">Nov 7, 2017</td>
  <td align="right" class="ng-binding">DL-50 - DL-50</td>
 </tr>
 <!-- end ngRepeat: record in records | orderBy: query.fullname -->
 <tr class="hand_cursor ng-scope" ng-click="create_dialog(record)" ng-repeat="record in records | orderBy: query.fullname" title="View Details">
  <td class="ng-binding">11032</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">Acosta, Ronald G.</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">Jan 16, 1992</td>
  <td align="right" class="ng-binding">DL-42 - DL-42</td>
 </tr>
 <!-- end ngRepeat: record in records | orderBy: query.fullname -->
 <tr class="hand_cursor ng-scope" ng-click="create_dialog(record)" ng-repeat="record in records | orderBy: query.fullname" title="View Details">
  <td class="ng-binding">72974</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">Acton, Leslie F.</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">Sep 1, 2011</td>
  <td align="right" class="ng-binding">F0518CB - Fld 5 East Sec B</td>
 </tr>
 <!-- end ngRepeat: record in records | orderBy: query.fullname -->
 <tr class="hand_cursor ng-scope" ng-click="create_dialog(record)" ng-repeat="record in records | orderBy: query.fullname" title="View Details">
  <td class="ng-binding">71894</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">Adams, Frances G.</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">Apr 2, 2018</td>
  <td align="right" class="ng-binding">F1007 - Spray Department</td>
 </tr>
 <!-- end ngRepeat: record in records | orderBy: query.fullname -->
 <tr class="hand_cursor ng-scope" ng-click="create_dialog(record)" ng-repeat="record in records | orderBy: query.fullname" title="View Details">
  <td class="ng-binding">32997</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">Adams, Susan M.</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">Aug 31, 2018</td>
  <td align="right" class="ng-binding">F1062 - Corp S16 Planation Management Hourlies</td>
 </tr>
 <!-- end ngRepeat: record in records | orderBy: query.fullname -->
 <tr class="hand_cursor ng-scope" ng-click="create_dialog(record)" ng-repeat="record in records | orderBy: query.fullname" title="View Details">
  <td class="ng-binding">10990</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">Adams, Michael B.</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">Aug 30, 2018</td>
  <td align="right" class="ng-binding">DL-04 - DL-04</td>
 </tr>
 <!-- end ngRepeat: record in records | orderBy: query.fullname -->
 <tr class="hand_cursor ng-scope" ng-click="create_dialog(record)" ng-repeat="record in records | orderBy: query.fullname" title="View Details">
  <td class="ng-binding">79358</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">Adams, Lisa B.</td>
  <td class="ng-binding">Apr 30, 2019</td>
  <td align="right" class="ng-binding">C1155 - C1155</td>
 </tr>
 <!-- end ngRepeat: record in records | orderBy: query.fullname -->
</tbody>
```

And here's my code:

```py
steven=soup.find("table",{"class":"table sticky-table-header table-hover ng-isolate-scope resize"})
        for row in steven.tbody.find_all('tr'):
            print(row.td.text)
```

Comment: Welcome to `Stack Overflow` community, I've corrected your question and provided an answer below. Kindly have a look into [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to get a quick answer for your future questions. Let me know in case if you need additional details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The issue that you are searching with the wrong attributes which is actually not within the source code at all.

Below you can achieve your goal:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

count = 0
for item in soup.findAll("tr", {"class": "hand_cursor ng-scope"}):
    for td in item.findAll("td")[1]:
        count += 1
        print(td)
print(f"Count is: {count}")
```

Output:

```
Abercrombie, Dave J.
Abeyta, Patricia F.
Acevedo, Patricia W.
Ackerman, Brittany B.
Acosta, Ronald G.
Acton, Leslie F.
Adams, Frances G.
Adams, Susan M.
Adams, Michael B.
Adams, Lisa B.
Count is: 10
```

Comment: i got 1 more question

Comment: how do i count tr

Comment: how to access first tr and its first td?